# Apache Cordova Extension in Visual Studio VS PhoneGap

Tags: apache, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Can anyone explain me what is the difference between Cordova Extension that VS offering for building hybrid apps and the PhoneGap Framework? I went to the PhoneGap API document site and it says "Note that Cordova used to be called PhoneGap" but on the other hand I found "Apache Cordova is the core open source project where development and contributions happen. vs "Adobe PhoneGap is a distribution of Apache Cordova that additionally provides integration with Adobe’s utilities and services". 
Is the Cordova Extension Visual Studio provides is Cordova PhoneGap combine thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova and Phonegap are almost same in coding techniques and API usage. There are few Difference like

- PhoneGap Extends Cordova by providing extra options like build tools etc
- Cordova use keyword "cordova" in commands while Phonegap uses "phonegap"
- cordova has a "serve" command that Phonegap doesn't
- Adding platforms seems to be done differently between the two commands ( phonegap uses "install" command, cordova uses "platform add" command
- few more..

MoreOver

keep these lines in mind to avoid confusion

> You can think of Apache Cordova as the engine that powers PhoneGap,
>   similar to how WebKit is the engine that powers Chrome or Safari

Comment: There is no mention of Visual Studio part here right?

Answer (score 0):

My opinion based on my experience:

- Cordova has a bigger community, has more plugins, updated faster, (is supported by Visual Studio, if this is important for you)
- Phonegap is built on top of Cordova and a has some extra features. It has a build (web based) system (which I don't use). The documentation has some nice examples. It has a very nice mobile app that shows the code updates immediately after you save the file. I really like this feature for mobile development.